# Changing folder name Batch filepath

Tags: batch-file, filepath

In my batch file, I first create a Lala file in folder: C:Lala-20160322-othercode and next day it creates the file in Lala-20160323-othercode and so on. In the same batch file, I want to use this created file. Now i do not know what to write after -filepath
Since Lala is in a differnt folder every time.
My batchfile is in folder above Lala-20160322-othercode. How can I do this?
The file itself is always called Lala, but on my  computer there are many folder (every day another folder) with Lala.
I am new to batch files. Many thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal
call "C:\folder\NameofPythonProgramm" Pythonfunction -filepath ????? -pythonfunction
```

First I had %1 where the questionmarks are, but I want this dynamic file path

Comment: I think you'll have to provide a copy of your code and provide some idea of what you're trying to do. For the bits you're not sure of you can just put comments in the code.

Comment: You have indicated below that you actually call the folder (eg) "Lala-20160322-othercode".  Could you [edit]  the question to contain that information.

Comment: How do you want the batch file to guess whether to use the January, February, or March folder?  Should it use the latest one?  The one that is the current directory, or the one containing the batch file? Perhaps a random one? (All of those are do-able, but you need to tell us which you want.)

Comment: Have you considered doing this in the Python?  Python is a lot nicer language than Batch.

Answer (score 0):

Save this as *Test.bat*, and run from its folder in open Cmd Prompt to access the file `Lala*` in the dir corresponding to your desired month. Let me know if any errors.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dir=c:\Lala-Months"
set "cur_month=August"
FOR /R "%dir%" %%G in (.) DO (set "mon=%%G"
    if not '!mon:%cur_month%=!'=='!mon!' echo %%G )
exit /b
```

Comment: Actually it is in the form Lala-20160322-othercode

I did not try your solution but it looks like it is not applicable after -filepath, is it? Besides your solution is only valid for August right?

Thanks anyway, I am new to this

Comment: The answer shows you how to access the only file in a target dir regardless of its name. If you have many different files in these dirs, let me know. If the answer works as per your question, pls upvote and accept it. You can use any function instead of ECHO with the file.